# Can't install ssh2-python wheel file with python 3.8 although it's for python3.8

Tags: python, python-wheel

I have the wheel file called `ssh2_python-0.23.0-cp38-cp38-win_amd64.whl` downloaded, and from my understanding the `cp38` part means that it has to be installed with python 3.8 and that the `win_amd64` part means that its for windows with an 64 bit architechture(which i have).

But if i try to install it with `python -m pip install ssh2_python-0.23.0-cp38-cp38-win_amd64.whl` i get the following error message:
`ERROR: ssh2_python-0.23.0-cp38-cp38-win_amd64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.`

Output of `python -V`: Python 3.8.5

I'm running the commands in a conda enviroment, does this make a difference?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ssh2_python-0.23.0-cp38-cp38-win_amd64.whl` is a wheel for 64-bit Python. It seems you have 32-bit Python. Either install 64-bit Python or use a 32-bit wheel.